# Strip paragraph tags from a block of text

Tags: preg-replace, paragraph

I am just trying to get my head round pregreplace, but it is driving me round the bend. All the examples I seem to find are a million times complicated than I need.
What im trying to do is just strip the paragraph tags from a block of text.

so.......

```
$text = '<p>Some block of text</p>';
```

should become

```
$afterreplace = 'Some block of text';
```

so im wondering how on earth I do this with preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

I kind of get this far but then, im not sure how to tell it to strip paragraphs........

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific example i would just use str_replace. It is way faster. 
You just replace "<p>" and "</p>" with " ".

Comment: I mean str_replace('/<p>.*<\/p>/s', '', $text)

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end >>

```
$text = '<p>Some Long Text String</p>';
$replaced = str_replace(array('<p>','</p>'),array('',''),$text);
```